# Averaging values in a data frame for a certain hour and month in R

Tags: r

I've been scouring the net but haven't found a solution to this quite possibly simple problem.

This is the half-hourly data using the library 'xts',

```
library(xts)
data.xts <- as.xts(1:nrow(data), as.POSIXct("2007-08-24 17:30:00") +
                  1800 * (1:nrow(data)))
data.xts <-as.data.frame(data.xts)
```

I changed it to data.frame because the original data is in data.frame format. Actually, in the original data frame, there is a time_stamp column and I prefer if I can just use the time_stamp column instead of using the 'xts' format.

How can I average every hourly data for a month so that I can plot a hourly time series of 24 hours for the different months?

For example,

```
 2007-08-24 17:30:00  1
 2007-08-25 17:00:00  47
 2007-08-25 17:30:00  48
 2007-08-26 17:00:00  95
```

would be averaged for the month of August 2007, etc.

Goal is to plot averaged 24-hourly time series for each month.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `cut`.  Do you want to average with breaks `0-1 hr, 1-2 hr`, etc. for every month?

Comment: Every hour, The first average is between 17:00 and 17:30 only, the second average is between 18:00 and 18:30, etc. for each month.  Can you explain how I can use `cut` in this case?

Comment: If it is every hour, why the breaks are only half an hour `17:00 and 17:30` instead of 17:00 to 18:00?

Comment: No data between 17:30 and 18:00. Just the data in 17:00 and 17:30 would represent the hour 17:00.

Comment: Okay, but you specify the breaks for 1 hour.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to use `cut` in this case?

Comment: Please check if the below solution works.  Also, what if you have data from different years?  DO you want to group by year also?

Comment: Yes, the actually data spans from August 2007 to Feb 2008.

Comment: So, you don't need the `year` as grouping? Anyway, I commented out the `year` as grouping line.  If you need, you can uncomment and use it.

Comment: If you want to remove those rows, you could use `dat1 <- na.omit(dat)` and then you apply the code on dat1

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I'm getting `Error: column 'time_stamp' has unsupported type`

Comment: Ahh, my format is POSIXlt... what to do?

Comment: You could convert it to `POSIXct` by `as.POSIXct`.  Let me test it.

Comment: It is a chain operator which connects operations on the `lhs` and `rhs` of `%>%`.  You can read about it by typing  `?'%>%'` in the R console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
res <- dat %>% 
           group_by(month=format(datetime, '%m'),
              #year=format(datetime, '%Y'), #if you need year also
              # as grouping variable
              hour=format(as.POSIXct(cut(datetime, breaks='hour')), '%H')) %>%
           summarise(Meanval=mean(val, na.rm=TRUE))   


 head(res,3)
 #  month hour     Meanval
 #1    01   00 -0.02780036
 #2    01   01 -0.06589948
 #3    01   02 -0.02166218
```

#### Update

If your `datetime` is `POSIXlt` you could convert it to `POSIXct`.

```
  dat$datetime <- as.POSIXlt(dat$datetime)
```

By running the above code, I get the error

```
   # Error: column 'datetime' has unsupported type
```

You could use `mutate` and convert the `datetime` to `POSIXct` class by `as.POSIXct`

```
  res1 <-  dat %>% 
               mutate(datetime= as.POSIXct(datetime)) %>%
               group_by(month=format(datetime, '%m'),
                 #year=format(datetime, '%Y'), #if you need year also
                 # as grouping variable
                  hour=format(as.POSIXct(cut(datetime, breaks='hour')), '%H')) %>%
               summarise(Meanval=mean(val, na.rm=TRUE))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.frame(datetime=seq(Sys.time(), by='1 hour', length.out=2000),
    val=rnorm(2000))
```

Comment: Thanks but a question... What if `datetime` has NAs in it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to average all the values for a given hour, *for all the days in a given month*, and do this for all months. So average all the values between midnight and 00:59:59 for all the days in a given month, etc.

I see that you want to avoid `xts` but `aggregate.zoo(...)` was designed for this, and avoids `dplyr` and `cut`.

```
library(xts)
# creates sample dataset...
set.seed(1)
data <- rnorm(1000)
data.xts <- as.xts(data, as.POSIXct("2007-08-24 17:30:00") +
                     1800 * (1:length(data)))

# using aggregate.zoo(...)
as.hourly <- function(x) format(x,"%Y-%m %H")
result    <- aggregate(data.xts,by=as.hourly,mean)
result    <- data.frame(result)
head(result)
#                result
# 2007-08 00 0.12236024
# 2007-08 01 0.41593567
# 2007-08 02 0.22670817
# 2007-08 03 0.23402842
# 2007-08 04 0.22175078
# 2007-08 05 0.05081899
```